# XmlReader Fail To Read Empty Nodes These Like Chrome Reader

Tags: php, xmlreader

i have a problem with reading empty elements formatted like `<eanCode/>`. After this element, `XmlReader` class is failing to read next element.

```
<EanCode/><Stock>15</Stock>

if ($reader->nodeType == XMLReader::ELEMENT) {
            switch ($reader->name) {

           case 'Stock':
                    $reader->read();
                    $stock = $reader->value;
            ECHO 'stokkk adet = '. $stock;
                    break;...
```

So, I decided to replace `<eanCode/>` with `<eanCode></eanCode>`. But it's difficult to write an algorithm. Can anyone supply a corresponding preg replace method, please?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

There's an issue in XMLReader.

If you have an empty element like this: `<test></test>`

You would get An ELEMENT and an END_ELEMENT.

However, if you use a self closing tag: `<test />`

You only get an ELEMENT, and NO END_ELEMENT.

An easy solution is to check if `$xmlReader->isEmptyElement` on each ELEMENT NODE. This will allow you to know if it's a self closing tag, you can then skip it.

Comment: I wouldn't call it "an issue" (there's no closing tag—what'd be the alternative?) but this answer has the correct explanation and the appropriate fix.

Comment: Had a similar problem, and this didn't help (although it should). Turns out, this was the problem:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45457014/detect-xml-self-closing-tags-with-php-xmlreader

Answer (score 0):

Please try:

```
$result = preg_replace('%<EanCode/>%', '<EanCode></EanCode>', $string);
```

Also you can check if element is empty:

```
$xml = new XMLReader();
$xml->XML('<tag attr="value" />');
$xml->read();
var_dump($xml->isEmptyElement);
```

Comment: this is absolutely correct. one different i used str_replace. but it can be formulate for anything like that? not specific

Comment: ? not clear for me. You can use regex for anything you want/need.

Comment: i mean a rule of `<anyTagName/> to <anyTagName></anyTagName>` not known tag name. note: sorry, it is difficult to explain how hard to learn engilish in our whole education system of turkey.

Comment: I might be too picky but I've always thought that using string manipulation functions to alter XML before processing it kind of beats the purpose of using proper XML libraries.

Comment: Yes, but as you see - the problem is with this: `XmlReader class is failing to read next element`. There is a problem - there is a solution :) I agree that the reason of the issue must be fixed in the class.